# how to set a variable imageview src?

Tags: java, android

I have 52 images of a deck of cards in my Drawable folder, with .png format.

I want to modify my android:src attribute of an ImageView, but using a var which saves the name of my image name. For example.

```
String nameOfCard="two_of_diamonds"; // and as I said I have an Image called two_of_diamonds in my Drawable folder
```

I tried several ways but I didn´t find the correct one.
If I use:  imageview.setImageResource(int) I need an int not a String reference.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to access drawable resources using name:

```
    Resources resources = getResources();
    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("two_of_diamonds",
            "drawable", getPackageName());

    imgView.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: aaah you guy are quick and clear. nº1 :)  Thaank you so much, it was the last step in my app, I´m so happy now jj

Answer (score 0):

Use **`getIdentifier()`**

> public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String
>   defPackage)

This will return the id. Use the id to set image resource for `imageview`.

For example,

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfCard,"drawable",getPackageName());
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object of Image like

```
class Image{
    String Name;
    int Id;
    public Image(String Name,int id){
        this.Name=Name;
        Id=id;
    }

}
```

Create an Array of Images

```
Image[] images = {new Image("name",R.drawable.name_of_image),...);
```

When Setting image use

```
for(Image i: images){
    if(i.Name.equals("desired")){
        imageview.setImageDrawable(i.Id);
    }
}
```

There must be a better approach to the problem than this. It is a very basic one.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this in Kotlin and used Deven's answer. It became:

```
    // THIS IS KOTLIN, NOT JAVA
    var diceRoll = dice.roll()
    var diceRoll2 = dice.roll()
    // Update the screen with the dice roll
    diceImage.setImageResource(getMyResource("dice_" + diceRoll))
    diceImage2.setImageResource(getMyResource("dice_" + diceRoll2))

fun getMyResource(imageName: String):Int{
    val resources: Resources = resources
    val resourceId: Int = resources.getIdentifier(
        imageName,
        "drawable", this.packageName
    )
    return resourceId
}
```